# can ram controllers be functionally kept from becoming idle?

Tags: c++, security, memory-management, hardware, ram

It's been shown to me that it is possible for the ram to be read without the system crashing or to be even taken over by a ram bypass.  http://www.google.com/patents/US6745308

However, the patent notes over and over that if a component isn't idle, it cannot be bypassed.  This seems to have been confirmed: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/70881/17872

Is it possible for c++ to prevent the ram controller from becoming idle while allowing the program to operate otherwise normally?  If so, how?

I understand that this could be a huge amount of code if possible, so please feel free to provide pseudocode (but actual code gets the long run check).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by "kept from becoming idle" and probably a whole range of parameters system parameters (bus speed, memory controller speed, CPU/GPU speed, etc). A trivial attempt may simply be to allocate a large amount of memory an simply write to every cell in that memory as fast as the processor can achieve. Multiple threads doing this may be required to saturate the bus, as single core may not issue enough write operations.

Having said that, I'm not sure that's necessarily a critical factor. Yes, if someone writes pathologically bad code, the patented method doesn't provide any benefit. But it also doesn't make a huge amount of drawback, vs. not having it. Yes, a few more gates, but it doesn't look like an extremely complex set of logic (compared to all the other stuff that goes into a modern processor or GPU). The key point is that quite often, systems are not 100% saturated, and the bypassing will succeed, which provides benefits.

I may of course have misunderstood what your question is, and why you are asking it....

Comment: the patent says that it needs the memory controller to become "idle" (however they define it) before they can bypass it & possibly hijack the system.  the ee.stack q may give an explanation why.  i'm wondering if it's possible for a program to function (albeit degraded) with 100% of the ram kept in this active state.  and hopefully seamlessly in a class/function

Comment: What is it you are trying to understand? As I understand it, the patent is about bypassing the main memory controller processing, by issuing memory requests more directly to the controller. This is only possible if there isn't a command already in progress (in other words, only possible when it is idle). Understandably we can't just "jump the queue" arbitrarily. Again, unless I'm missing something - I'm not that experienced in reading patents, and the language is different from "regular stuff", because it's intentionally vague and cryptic to not give too much leeway with similar ideas.

Comment: If you look at figure 3, it seems to agree with my description of "if not possible, use northbridge interface" - so the bypass is only used if possible, otherwise use "traditional method".

Comment: that's exactly what i'm hoping to do: prevent them from ever even entering the queue (much less jump it) by keeping the memory controller not "idle" as they define it as a security measure to prevent the bypass from "hijacking"

Comment: What are you on about? Can you please describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve? What "hijacking" are we talking of here?

Comment: well, it's just been shown to me that i may have been mistaken, and a "hijacking" may be all but impossible (comments), so maybe nevermind http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/70999/17872

Comment: Ah, so you were worried about someone actually reading the content of RAM without using the processor, or something like that?

Comment: yes, and even somehow tapping into the currently running system, but i've found no evidence except for what i thought was this patent

Comment: Well, with hardware acccess, and some carefully placed probes between the memory controller and the processor, you could record all memory activity. But it would of course produce an enormous amount of data, most of which is pretty useless from a security aspect. If you know what you are looking for, perhaps one of these can be used: http://www.agilent.com/about/newsroom/presrel/2009/09nov-em09162.html

But it'd not be entirely trivial to sneak that past someone without being noticed... ;)

Comment: so awesome.  ty!  can it be attached while the target machine is running?

Comment: Only if you can hot-swap memory in the machine.